# Could not find "Advance Option" in Replace value window with Power BI Desktop

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am using power BI desktop, I loaded a excel file, I want to clean up some data using replace option. I want to replace null & some garbage values. I selected the column & get Replace option window but it has only two text boxes, for some reason advance option where I can write query to replace the text does not appear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

replace a value with this method and then you can edit the step from address/query bar.[image: example]